# React native auto linking issue in Android (RN 0.61.5)

Tags: react-native

I was using react-native 0.59.1 and recently migrated to react-native 0.61.5 after that when I run `react-native run-android` I get the following error.

[image]

Even with the error the project builds and run properly.

I have heard about auto-linking and as suggested in the error I have unlinked the dependency using the command shown in the error and also run `react-native link`. After that, the project builds and works fine in iOS but throwing the following error in Android

[image]

Comment: try to unlink netinfo and then relink it..

Comment: Could it be your android/build.gradle has not included the dependencies? Since you have ran unlink command, it's expected to remove dependency from both OS.

Comment: @TommyLeong the unlink command removed the dependencies from both.

Comment: That's what im pointing out. So you might want to re-append the depdency at your android/build.gradle. Eg `implementation project(':react-native-geolocation')`

Comment: @TommyLeong Okay, but it should be done automatically?

Comment: Yes, when you perform `yarn add abcDependency`, auto linking will be performed. hence you will see the implementation code will be added on Android. On iOS side, im not so sure. Cause I have difficulty on Podfile too.

Comment: @TommyLeong I am using npm.

Comment: Yea, then you could try with `npm add abcDependency` lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with my react-native upgrade. I haven't updated the `MainApplication.java` file properly. I have fixed it by updating `getPackages()` method in `MainApplication.java` file as follow

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  return packages;
}
```

Now everything works properly.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to try to run `react-native unlink netinfo`. Once you've unlinked the library you should use `cocoapods`, not `react-native link ...`. This is because in React Native v0.61 you no longer manually link 3rd party libraries. Try running:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Comment: It is already working on iOS. Android is where the problem occurs. How can I solve it in Android?

Comment: Which NetInfo version do you use? Did you migrate with react native upgrade helper? Did you run jetify?

Comment: I'm using NetInfo v4.6.1. Yes, I have used the migration guide and jetifier is running when executing `react-native run-android`. I'm having the linking issue with all native packages only in Android.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up your project and build again?

Comment: Yes, I have run `./gradlew` clean at /android and rerun the `react-native run-android` command from project folder. Still, it is not working.